# Am I using CSS grid wrong?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "header header header header header"
        "article main main main main"
        "article main main main main"
        "article main main main main"
        "footer footer footer footer footer";
    grid-template-columns: 20% auto auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: 15% auto auto auto 10%;
    grid-gap: 3px;
}

.hBanner {
    grid-area: header;
    border: solid 2px black;
    text-align: center;
}
/*  ^^Head Banner^^  */
.aHead {
    grid-area: article;
    border: solid 2px black;
    text-align: center;
}
    .aHead h3 {
        font-size: 3vw;
    }
    .aHead ul {
        font-size: 2vw;
    }
    .aHead li {
        list-style-position: inside;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

/*  ^^Article Headings^^ */
.mBody {
    grid-area: main;
    border: solid 2px black;
    text-align: center;
}
    .mBody iframe {
        background-image: url(https://www.clker.com/cliparts/4/b/2/9/151641893861684429we-are-awesome-clipart.med.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        background-position: center;
    }

/*  ^^Main Body^^  */
.updates {
    grid-area: footer;
    border: solid 2px black;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
    .updates p {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
        transform: translateX(100%);
        -moz-animation: scroll-left 13s linear infinite;
        -webkit-animation: scroll-left 13s linear infinite;
        animation: scroll-left 13s linear infinite;
    }
    @-moz-keyframes scroll-left {
        0%  { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
        100%    { -moz-transform: translateX(-131%); }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes scroll-left {
        0%  { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
        100%    { -webkit-transform: translateX(-131%); }
    }
    @keyframes scroll-left {
        0%   { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); 
               -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
               transform: translateX(100%);
             }
        100% { -moz-transform: translateX(-131%);
               -webkit-transform: translateX(-131%);
               transform: translateX(-131%);
              }
    }
    /*  ^^Footer Banner^^  */
/*
canvas {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px gray;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}
        */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyBlog</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyBlog.css">
    <script src="MyBlog.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <!--Header-->
        <div class="hBanner">My Blog</div>
        <!--***********************************************-->
        <!--Entries from Google DOCS-->
        <div class="aHead">
            <h3>
                Entries<h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vRQPbexsSqrD5E7tzli9iZtQMav7b94kvCncT8t1o07b32jg_5_CrbxtyAz2dfxyOL-UNVz_g4nM4eT/pub?embedded=true" target="myFrame">Entry 01</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vTcHl05YdAILSCPM-BeH5y8eyw0gySOmNZyktl7Dj4PMoJtUaZfaWUO8EbxyxqyieNbeZ9_XnVcmect/pub?embedded=true" target="myFrame">Entry 02</a></li>
                <!--    <li><a href="?embedded=true" target="myFrame">Entry 03</a></li>
                        <li><a href="?embedded=true" target="myFrame">Entry 04</a></li>
                        <li><a href="?embedded=true" target="myFrame">Entry 05</a></li> -->
                    </ul>
        </div>
        <!--***********************************************-->
        <!--DOCS viewer-->
        <div class="mBody">
            <iframe name="myFrame"></iframe>

            <!--***********************************************-->
            <!--Game-->
            <!--    <canvas id="canvas" width="500px" height="400px"></canvas>  -->
        </div>

        <!--NEWS banner-->
        <div class="updates">
            <p>Welcome To My Blog!!</p>
        </div>
        <!--***********************************************-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am attempting to create a blog for personal development and I currently running into an issue with positioning elements using grid. I had some success before using float, but from my understanding, that is more or less deprecated.

This is what I have so far:

**MY CODE

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template:
        'header header header header header'
        'article main main main main'
        'article main main main main'
        'article main main main main'
        'footer footer footer footer footer';
    grid-gap: 3px;
}

.hBanner {
    grid-area: header;
    border: solid 2px black;
    text-align: center;
}
/*  ^^Head Banner^^  */
.aHead {
    grid-area: article;
    border: solid 2px black;
    text-align: center;
}
    .aHead h3 {
        font-size: 3vw;
    }
    .aHead ul {
        font-size: 2vw;
    }
    .aHead li {
        list-style-position: inside;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

/*  ^^Article Headings^^ */
.mBody {
    grid-area: main;
    border: solid 2px black;
    text-align: center;
}
    .mBody iframe {
        background-image: url(https://www.clker.com/cliparts/4/b/2/9/151641893861684429we-are-awesome-clipart.med.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        background-position: center;
    }

/*  ^^Main Body^^  */
.updates {
    grid-area: footer;
    grid-row-start: 5;
    grid-row-end: 6;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    border: solid 2px black;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
    .updates p {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
        transform: translateX(100%);
        -moz-animation: scroll-left 13s linear infinite;
        -webkit-animation: scroll-left 13s linear infinite;
        animation: scroll-left 13s linear infinite;
    }
    @-moz-keyframes scroll-left {
        0%  { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
        100%    { -moz-transform: translateX(-131%); }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes scroll-left {
        0%  { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
        100%    { -webkit-transform: translateX(-131%); }
    }
    @keyframes scroll-left {
        0%   { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); 
               -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
               transform: translateX(100%);
             }
        100% { -moz-transform: translateX(-131%);
               -webkit-transform: translateX(-131%);
               transform: translateX(-131%);
              }
    }
    /*  ^^Footer Banner^^  */
/*
canvas {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px gray;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}
        */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyBlog</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyBlog.css">
    <script src="MyBlog.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <!--Header-->
        <div class="hBanner">My Blog</div>
        <!--***********************************************-->
        <!--Entries from Google DOCS-->
        <div class="aHead">
            <h3>
                Entries<h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="https:///pub?embedded=true" target="myFrame">Entry 01</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https:///pub?embedded=true" target="myFrame">Entry 02</a></li>
                <!--    <li><a href="?embedded=true" target="myFrame">Entry 03</a></li>
                        <li><a href="?embedded=true" target="myFrame">Entry 04</a></li>
                        <li><a href="?embedded=true" target="myFrame">Entry 05</a></li> -->
                    </ul>
        </div>
        <!--***********************************************-->
        <!--DOCS viewer-->
        <div class="mBody">
            <iframe name="myFrame"></iframe>

            <!--***********************************************-->
            <!--Game-->
            <!--    <canvas id="canvas" width="500px" height="400px"></canvas>  -->
        </div>

        <!--NEWS banner-->
        <div class="updates">
            <p>Welcome To My Blog!!</p>
        </div>
        <!--***********************************************-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in my CSS that my layout is intended to be look similar to this:
'H H H H H'
'A M M M M'
'A M M M M'
'A M M M M'
'F F F F F'
Very simple layout I know, But I am now stuck as to if I'm placing the syntax incorrectly or if I am just typing out some none sense. Any help will be appreciated.

EDITed:
I made some changes to the CSS. It seems to be working if you run the snipets, but for some reason it's not working right if I run it locally.
[screen capture][local]
[screen capture][stackoverflow]
They're previewing using Chrome browser, and I'm using Visual studio community 2019 to edit my text. I may have more problems than just my poor coding skills.

Comment: remove this `grid-row-start: 5;
    grid-row-end: 6;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 4;` not need since you are defining area

Comment: Even though that doesn't quite fix my problem, I do see why I need to get rid of those lines. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you plan to do your site easily accessible on tablets and mobile phones you should definitely use grid or flexboxes for your layout. Ditching float is the right way to go.

If I understand correctly your only issue atm is the width of the footer. If that is the case, you just need to change one row:

```
.updates {
...
grid-column-end: 6;
...
}
```

Comment: I should've proofread my work before posting, but I did get rid of the grid-row/column-start/end portion, after it had been pointed out. unfortunately the page is still coming out undesired. I will try sizing the columns/rows to see if that'll work

Comment: turns out that is just my browser wanting to act funny. I editted my CSS using your advise and it works now so I'll accept your answer with a follow-up.
The changes that I made were first removing grid-row/column-start/end from the .updates style, and I added grid-template-columns/rows to the .grid-container style.